# Water line under the sink to fridge ice make isn't working. No water will come through the line. How can I clean it out?

Tags: refrigerator

This is the water line under the sink. Water is coming out of valve,but not the line.
[image]

Comment: Why not just replace it?  Get a stainless mesh reinforce one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is the part not allowing the water to flow? I would start by disconnecting the line everywhere there is a connection, turn the valve on and see where the restriction might be. It could be the ice maker not allowing water to come in. The valve on the ice maker could be bad. If you find a hose restricted, replace it rather than trying to clear it out.